# Convert and calculate an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

[image]

I have an array like the one you can see in the pic. I have seen array with objects in it, array with numbers and/or strings. But I don't know how to deal with this kind of array. It looks like each line is an object in the array but there is no "{}".  (Sorry, I am new to javascript)

My question is..I want a new array like below, how can I convert it?

```
    newArray = [
       {
       time:Q2.14,
       percent:...
    },
       {
       time:Q3.14,
       percent:...
    },
          {
       time:Q4.14,
       percent:...
    },
       ....
    ]
```

The percent is the value for the current time devided by sum of all numbers.
Appreciate!

Comment: You should learn how to work with arrays and objects before trying to use the inspector. The inspector does not necessarily represent data in a way that is syntactically synonymous with the way you would write it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really an array. It's an object with sub-objects.

```
var outputArray = [];
for( var prop in notQuiteArray ) {
  outputArray.push({time: prop, percent: notQuiteArray[prop]});
}
```

where `notQuiteArray` is the object you were inspecting.